# Not able access AEM author using JcrUtils.getRepository

Tags: aem-6

I want to access one author crx from another author CRX. For example, I am trying to make a connection from Dev author to QA author. I am using JCRUtil class to access  the repository . Below is code snippet

```
try {
   repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");
} catch (RepositoryException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is throwing below exception -

javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the following settings:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: http://localhost:4502/crx/server
```

The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JndiRepositoryFactory: declined
```

Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.

I went through some article and forum and it suggested to add below dependency.

org.apache.jackrabbit

jackrabbit-jcr2dav

2.6.0

Even after adding above dependency it is working.  Can you please let me if I am missing something or is there another way to make the connection between two author instance? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Get Repository API is generally used to connect to the instance from a standalone web application. What is your actual requirement to connect from one environment to other?

If you are looking for content sync, there are multiple options like using package manager or Grabbit etc..